# Issue in a declared factory: AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

//in the html, the following 2 files are attached.
//          <script src="lib/sockjs-0.3.4.min.js"></script>
//          <script src="lib/vertxbus.min.js"></script>

app.factory('serverData',function(){
    var eb = new vertx.EventBus('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx');
    var x = {};
    eb.send( "com.find.web.ed",{"Em":'user@find.com',"Pw":'123'}, 
        function(reply){
            x = reply;
        });
    var fact = {};
    fact.getData = function(){
        return x;
    };

    return fact;
});

app.controller('mainController',function($scope,serverData){

});
```

### In the above code, i am trying to declare a factory to get data from  a vertex server. It is not working, can some one help.?

It is working well when It is used in a controller. See the code.

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('mainController',function($scope,$log){
$rootScope.user = {user :'user@find.com',password :'123'};
$rootScope.reply = {};

$scope.eb = new vertx.EventBus('http://100.100.100.100:8000');

$scope.loginFunction = function(){
            $scope.eb.send( "com.find.web.ed", 
                {"Em":$scope.user.user,"Pw":$scope.user.password},
                function(reply){
                 $rootScope.reply = reply;
                 $log.warn($rootScope.reply);
} 
);
}
});
```

Comment: Need more info on what's not working... Can you confirm you are able to execute the `eb.send()` method and populate `x` without using Angular? Assuming the event bus code works, are you hoping to call `eb.send()` every time `serverData.getData()` is called?

Comment: @AnthonyChu , I had updated the Question, Please see above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your factory code will only get the data once and it has no way of responding to the controller. I think you might be looking for something like this instead where `send()` is called every time and the controller provides a callback...

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.factory('serverData', function(){
    var eb = new vertx.EventBus('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx');
    var fact = {};

    fact.getData = function(user, password, callback){
        // call send and pass it the callback function
        eb.send( "com.find.web.ed",
                 {"Em": user,"Pw": password}, 
                 callback
        );
    };

    return fact;
});

app.controller('mainController', function($scope, serverData){
    $scope.user = {user :'user@find.com',password :'123'};
    $scope.reply = {};

    serverData($scope.user.user, $scope.user.password, function (reply) {
        $scope.reply = reply;
        // might need $scope.$apply() here
    });
});
```

You can also do this via a `$q` promise...

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.factory('serverData', function($q){
    var eb = new vertx.EventBus('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx');
    var fact = {};

    fact.getData = function(user, password){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        // call send and pass it the callback function
        eb.send( "com.find.web.ed",
                 {"Em": user,"Pw": password}, 
                 function (reply) {
                     deferred.resolve(reply);
                 }
                 // also should reject on error
        );
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    return fact;
});

app.controller('mainController', function($scope, serverData){
    $scope.user = {user :'user@find.com',password :'123'};
    $scope.reply = {};

    serverData($scope.user.user, $scope.user.password)
        .then(function (reply) {
            $scope.reply = reply;
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider your following code

```
eb.send( "com.find.web.ed",{"Em":'user@find.com',"Pw":'123'}, 
        function(reply){
            x = reply;
        });
```

you are setting x with reply in callback. This is the problem. Your are replacing your entire object with reply object. And your fact.getData method pointing to old x, which is {}.

To solve create x in you fact object, or you can use promise as well.